# How can I access an ImageView inside of AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have some code that creates a popup and assign it an XML layout that has two ImageView items in it.

```
popupWindow.setTitle("New note");
popupWindow.setMessage("choose the type of note to create");

View noteChoices = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addnotepopup, null);
popupWindow.setView(noteChoices);

popupWindow.setPositiveButton(null, null);

popupWindow.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //
    }
});

popupWindow.show();
```

addnotepopup.xml has the two ImageView items

How can I add click listeners to those two items? When I try doing it the same way as any other button, findViewById() returns a null value

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recordnoteoption"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/medium_mic"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/typenoteoption"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" 
            android:src="@drawable/medium_keyboard"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: pls put the xml layout for `R.layout.addnotepopup`? Also put the code  you using for `findViewById`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```

or if you want:

```
  noteChoices.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```

Comment: using noteChoices worked, I had tried using popupWindow.findViewById() before but it wasn't working... thanks!